# Construct json with multiple identical keys in Qt5

Tags: json, qt5

I want to generate a json that looks like this:

```
{
    "myRepeatedKey": "test_data_1",
    "myRepeatedKey": "test_data_2",
    "myRepeatedKey": "test_data_3",
    "myRepeatedKey": "test_data_4"
}
```

using Qt5. My naive approach looks like this:

```
QVariantMap map;
map_fill["myRepeatedKey"]="test_data_1";
map_fill["myRepeatedKey"]="test_data_2";
map_fill["myRepeatedKey"]="test_data_3";
map_fill["myRepeatedKey"]="test_data_4";
QJsonDocument doc=QJsonDocument::fromVariant(map);
qDebug()<<doc.toJson();
```

Since this replaces data for the entry, this outputs (not surprisingly) this:

```
}
    "myRepeatedKey": "test_data_4"
}
```

So how could I do this in Qt5?

PS: According to [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) it is recommended but not required for names in name/value pairs in json data to be unique, so even though what I am asking for is not recommended practice, I would still know how to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: Qt Json implementation does not allow this. Sorry =/

Comment: @Vin Put that in an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 0):

I think adding duplicate keys is a bad idea. You should use json array (QJsonArray) in this case.

```
QJsonArray array;
array.append("test_data_1");
array.append("test_data_2");
array.append("test_data_3");
array.append("test_data_4");

QJsonObject o;
o["myArray"] = array;

QJsonDocument doc(o);
qDebug() << doc.toJson();
```

Output will be

```
{
    "myArray": [
        "test_data_1",
        "test_data_2",
        "test_data_3",
        "test_data_4"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I explicitly stated in the question that I KNEW it was not best practice (a.k.a. "a bad idea"). But thanks anyways!